# JavaScript 2D collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas with boxes that bounce of one another, but they get stuck in each other and I'm not to sure why. I added a bit of a bounce but that made it worse

http://passion4web.co.uk/ben/collision1.html

P.s Beginner

Comment: Please paste the relevant code and HTML here in the question.

Comment: Looks like the checking interval is not fine enough. Pretty cool side effect, btw.

Comment: there's no JS, HTML or Canvas in the question - the problem is actually abstract, and independent of the implementation environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem as far as I can see is these two lines:

```
//bounce
this.speed.y += 0.5;
this.speed.x += 0.5;
```

where you modify the speed of the boxes, without taking into account the current direction of movement.

This will end up causing the classic problem with collision detection algorithms where the new point (calculated after modifying the object's speed) is still within collision range, resulting in two objects just sticking together.

One approach to this problem is to perform the collision detection based on the *projected* future position rather than on the current position (i.e. add the speed vector to the position vector and *then* do collision detection).

Strictly speaking this will result in the collisions happening just *outside* the box rather than inside, but if your sampling rate is high enough the visual effect should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it is to do with when you are multiplying the speeds by -1. Because if the two colliding boxes still overlap next loop through the script they change direction back toward eachother.

I can think of two solutions:

1) If you want a soft bounce, just use add and subtract form the speed variables eg/ speed.x += 0.5;

2) alternatively if you want a rigid kind of bounce, set the speed variables to a certain ammount eg/ speed.x = 5; If you want it to match the current speed use abs: speed.x = Math.abs(speed.x);

For either of these solutions to work however you need to run slightly different scripts depending on where the object collides (top, bottom, right, left) so if it collided on the right you could use speed.x = -Math.abs(speed.x)

Hope that makes sense and helps :)